# Chroot/Jail ? Problem after update to Debian 12 Bookworm

Tags: firefox, segmentation-fault, debian, upgrade, fakeroot

After Upgrade of Bullseye to Bookworm, i cannot use chroot/jail in three cases.

1. I cannot build debian packages using fakeroot tool. The build ends with: "fakeroot debian/rules clean subprocess returned exit status 139" and dmesg: `[83596.375961] rules[77366]: segfault at 7fffaf433d00 ip 00007f2fb627b2b7 sp 00007fffaf433d00 error 6 in libc.so.6[7f2fb6245000+155000] likely on CPU 1 (core 1, socket 0) [83596.375974] Code: e6 ff ff ba 01 00 00 00 e9 d6 ed ff ff 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 57 41 56 41 55 41 54 49 89 d4 55 53 48 89 fb 48 81 ec 08 05 00 00 <48> 89 34 24 89 4c 24 3c 64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 84 24`
2. Firefox cannot use tabs: The new tabs remain empty with dmesg: `[84119.560359] firefox-bin[77813]: segfault at 0 ip 0000557abfd72560 sp 00007fff4ed44820 error 6 in firefox-bin[557abfd5d000+a2000] likely on CPU 2 (core 2, socket 0) [84119.560384] Code: 53 48 89 fb 4c 8b 35 77 5a 0a 00 49 8b 36 e8 07 b0 fe ff 49 8b 36 bf 0a 00 00 00 e8 ba b0 fe ff 48 8d 05 0b 81 0a 00 48 89 18 <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 23 00 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00 55 48 89 e5 48`
3. Chrome cannot use tabs: [image]

Is there any way how to make fixed without complete reinstall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be weirdly specific, but I had the same issue and was able to solve it by removing an old package that I had installed.
The package is `icaclient`, which is used to connect to Citrix programs.

```
Entfernen von icaclient (22.5.0.16) ...
Removed "/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/AppProtectionService-install.service".
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/AppProtectionService-remove.service → /lib/systemd/system/AppProtectionService-remove.service.
Failed to disable unit: Unit file ctxlogd.service does not exist.
Entfernen von libidn11:amd64 (1.33-3) ...
```

I assume something weird in regard to AppProtectionService played into this.

Hope this helps, in any case watch out for external applications.